# How To Get All Columns From a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have a document library which contains folders and document sets. I am trying to decide which to use for this case, is there a better option??

So I have the library known as 'TestTracking', which contains folders (or document sets depending which is the best option). I wish there was a way to have different columns for the files that are within the document sets/folders as it gets confusing having to mess with the content type.

Each folder in the library is a name, nested in that folder are files that have a retention date, start date, file type, and name of the file. There is a name value for both the folder as well as the file inside the folder, and when I use REST API, I cannot seem to find that value anywhere in my response. How can I filter/query/expand the results. This is a bit more confusing than normal list operations.

Here is my url for my AJAX call:

```
var libraryUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestTracker')/items?select=Files$expand=Children";
```

What I am trying to access. In the parent(TestTracker Library), each folder has three columns showing relevant to that column. Name (default), Team, and OnBoardingDate. Within that folder, what I need to grab is the Name (default), Type (choice column for what the file is), and isRetained, a calculated column based off the OnBoardingDate.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch SharePoint default "Name" field using REST API? Or is this the custom column you created in library?

Comment: @GaneshSanap the default one. I will list what my fields are that I am trying to access in OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using REST endpoint like below:

```
var libraryUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestTracker')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,File_x0020_Type,isRetained";
```

Assuming `isRetained` is correct **internal name** of your column. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

In above query:

- FileLeafRef: returns file name with example (SharePoint default column)
- File_x0020_Type: returns file type (SharePoint default column)

**Example XML response**:

```
<m:properties>
    <d:FileLeafRef>TestDocument.docx</d:FileLeafRef>
    <d:File_x0020_Type>docx</d:File_x0020_Type>
</m:properties>
```

---

**Update from comments**:

To get only files & exclude folders, add filter on [FSObjType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee537053(v=office.15)) property like:

```
var libraryUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestTracker')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,File_x0020_Type,isRetained,FSObjType&$filter=FSObjType eq 0"
```

Comment: My data type is JSON, and FileLeafRef doesn't return anything upon completion of the request. How come if I have one folder with one file in it, the call returns two objects in the response instead of one nested one? Gonna make it a lot harder to manipulate

Comment: XML response was just for example. You will get the same response in JSON as well. And yes, it does return two objects - 1 for folder & 1 for a file. To get only files / folders, you can add filter on the `FSObjType` property as given in updated answer.

Comment: gotcha. How can I pull the actual file through the REST API? I try to do the following `/items?$expand=Employee&$select=Team,Attachments,AttachmentFiles,Title,Certification,OnboardingDate,IsRetained,Employee/Title` and I get the error that `The field or property 'Attachments' does not exist.`

Comment: `Attachments` column does not exist in **document library**. So, try using endpoint like: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestTracker')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,File_x0020_Type,isRetained,FSObjType,File&$expand=File&$filter=FSObjType eq 0`